CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKLoginKit" Facebook Login Setup
I'm currently stuck on this part when I try to run pod install in my flutter project.
This is what I have in my pubspec.yaml
flutter_facebook_auth: ^6.1.1
flutter_login_facebook: ^1.9.0

This is what I also have in my Podfile
platform :ios, '12.0'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

I deleted my Podfile.lock and run pod repo update before running pod install. I tried to use lower versions of the two libraries but still to no avail. This is the error.
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKLoginKit":
In Podfile:
FBSDKLoginKit

flutter_facebook_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_auth/ios`) was resolved to 6.0.4, which depends on
  FBSDKLoginKit (~> 16.3.1)

flutter_login_facebook (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_login_facebook/ios`) was resolved to 1.9.0, which depends on
  FBSDKLoginKit (= 16.2.1)

Can someone help me on this?
Versions
Pod : 1.15.2
Xcode : 15.3 Build version 15E204a
iOS SDKs: iOS 17.4

Try to downgrade versions:
flutter_facebook_auth: 6.0.3
flutter_login_facebook: 1.9.0

I can't build because I didn't configure my project with facebook keys and etc.
See details here: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_login_facebook

But I got no longer error on pod repo update

@IaroslavSiniugin thanks for the help, but as I'm following again this docu https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/ , in AppDelegate.swift,  I ran to an error No such module 'FacebookCore'
../ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:17:7, and if I add Facebook Core in Podfile, it goes back to compatibility issue again

@IaroslavSiniugin can you please put your comments above to your answer so that I can accept that as an answer? thanks

Ok @ramedju it's done. I edited my initial answer

Please list your current pods version, iOS SDK version and xCode version
Try to downgrade versions: flutter_facebook_auth: 6.0.3
flutter_login_facebook: 1.9.0`
I can't build because I didn't configure my project with facebook keys and etc. See details here: pub.dev/packages/flutter_login_facebook `
But I got no longer error on pod repo update

updated @Iaroslav Siniugin
